# Delete __HIVE_DEFAULT_PARTITION__ USING spark Notebook

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, azure-synapse, spark-notebook

Tried everything for a few hours to delete a record with a column partition value of `__HIVE_DEFAULT_PARTITION__` within my delta lake table using a spark notebook.  I figured it out and will post the answer.  For the record my partition column is named Period.
This occurs when your partition column has a NULL value.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure no other notebooks are updating the delta lake table when you run this.
The partition column in my table is named Period.
sourceFile is a variable containing the location of the storage account container and folder to effect.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.types import *

spark.conf.set("spark.databricks.delta.retentionDurationCheck.enabled",False) 
from delta.tables import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

deltaTable = DeltaTable.forPath(spark, sourceFile)
deltaTable.delete("Period is NULL")
deltaTable.vacuum(0)
```